# Why submitting an invalid post breaks a micropost feed (Railstutorial chapter 11)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I'm about halfway through chapter 11 of Hartl's Railstutorial where it's showing how to add a micropost feed to a home page. It does this through the code:

```
@feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

where feed is the method

```
  def feed
    Micropost.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end
```

Now in homepage where the micropost feed is suppose to be you have a partial containing:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

Now the tutorial mentions that on the homepage, if you submit an invalid micropost, it will break:

> "on failed micropost submission, the Home page expects an @feed_items
>   instance variable, so failed submissions currently break."

I don't understand the explanation as to why this breaks. Shouldn't `@feed_items` consist of all the other valid microposts from the database? So that even if you submit an invalid post, @feed_items gets populated with the previous valid microposts? I don't understand how an invalid micropost is able to affect @feed_items, especially since @feed_items draws microposts from the database, which only contains valid microposts because of validations present on microposts that are submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because then `@feed_items` will be `nil` and when you call: `@feed_items.any?` in your view, that will be `nil.any?` and that will fail with this error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how @feed_items becomes nil since it is drawing microposts from the database, which has valid microposts. Am I mising something here?

Comment: Because if the micropost submission fails, then you wont have a valid `id` in your `params`, so your `feed` method won't work and so your `@feed_items` won't be populated. Is that clear now?

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a micropost, you call the `create` action of the `MicropostsController`:

```
def create
@micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
if @micropost.save
  flash[:success] = "Micropst created"
  redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'static_pages/home'
end
end
```

If the micropost saves successfully, you are redirected. The `home` action of the `StaticPagesController` is called. `@micropost` and `@feed_items` are both created then. Everything runs fine.

If the micropost does **not** save successfully, then you stay in the `StaticPagesController`, and try to render the `static_pages/home` template. For this, you need `@micropost` and `@feed_items` instance variables, but at this point you only have defined `@micropost`.

That's why the proposed workaround is to define the `@feed_items` instance variable as an empty array, before trying to render the template.